# Ubuntu 14.04 Software Center won;t open after download of update terminated

Tags: updates, software-center

Attempted an update of Ubuntu 14.04 but download was terminated by a broken internet connection now software center won't open.  Is it possible to clean out partial download and try update again?  Is the partial download the reason that the software center won't open?

wise tech

Comment: list down the output of running the command `software-center` in a terminal